# How to edit player info

Tags: arma-3

I was playing Arma 3 Breaking Point when I saw this in the player list:

[image]

Where can I enter those information so I can show my unit's informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an XML file containing all these informations, and then link it in your profile. [Here](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/squad.xml) is a complete tutorial from the BI Wiki.